# How to group items by month and year using itertools.groupby()

Tags: python, django

**Problem:** I am trying to take a sorted list and group it based on the month and year but having trouble returning the grouped value correctly...

Assuming this data, we have a title and date/time list that has been ordered by datetime

```py
lst = [
    {'title': 'in the past','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    {'title': 'Just another event','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 19, 7)},
    {'title': 'earlier today 9am','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 9, 0)},
    {'title': 'greater than .now()','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 23, 0)},
    {'title': 'another one','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 10, 0)},
    {'title': 'Me testing the latest event','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 12, 0)},
    {'title': '18 Nov 20','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 20, 27)},
    {'title': '18 January 2021','date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 20, 0)},
    {'title': '18 March 21','date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 20, 0)}
]
```

Then to group it, run it through `itertools.groupby()`

```py
from itertools import groupby

def loop_tupe():
    diction = {}
    for key,group in groupby(lst, key=lambda x: (x['date_time'].month, x['date_time'].year)):
        for element in group:
            append_value(diction, key, element)
    return diction
```

After grouping it by the month and year the returned result looks like

```js
{
    (3, 2020): {'title': 'in the past', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    (10, 2020): [
        {'title': 'Just another event', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 19, 7)},
        {'title': 'earlier today 9am', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 9, 0)},
        {'title': 'greater than .now()', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 23, 0)},
        {'title': 'another one', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 10, 0)},
        {'title': 'Me testing the latest event', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 12, 0)}
        ],
    (11, 2020): {'title': '18 Nov 20', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 20, 27)},
    (1, 2021): {'title': '18 January 2021', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 20, 0)},
    (3, 2021): {'title': '18 March 21', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 20, 0)}
}
```

It has been grouped correctly, however the dates are within a tuple whereas I would need them as one "value", and while it's in this format I am unable to loop over it in the way I would with the original list.

I realise it has something to do with the way I'm using the anonymous function within the `groupby()` (and maybe how the return result is created perhaps?) but I'm unsure how else to apply a month and year grouping within it.

**Question:** What can I do to group my original data by month & year while also keeping its format relatively similar to the list going in?

---

Edit

The `append_value` function that I'm using

```py
def append_value(dict_obj, key, value):
    if key in dict_obj:
        if not isinstance(dict_obj[key], list):
            dict_obj[key] = [dict_obj[key]]
        dict_obj[key].append(value)
    else:
        dict_obj[key] = value
```

---

Edit 2

So far this is the closest I'm getting to a solution.

I have changed the function used in `groupby` to take the datetime and change it into a string to be compared. (I've left the print in there to visualise)

```py
def loop_str(to_sort):
    output={}
    for key,group in groupby(to_sort, key=lambda item: item['date_time'].strftime('%B %Y')):
        for element in group:
            append_value(output,key,element)
    return output
```

Doing so gives me this output

```py
{
    'March 2020': {
        'title': 'in the past', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 18, 0, 0)
    },
    'October 2020': [
        {'title': 'Just another event', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 19, 7)},
        {'title': 'earlier today 9am', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 9, 0)},
        {'title': 'greater than .now()', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 23, 0)},
        {'title': 'another one', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 10, 0)},
        {'title': 'Me testing the latest event', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 12, 0)}
    ],
    'November 2020': {
        'title': '18 Nov 20', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 20, 27)
    },
    'January 2021': {
        'title': '18 January 2021', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 20, 0)
    },
    'March 2021': {
        'title': '18 March 21', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 20, 0)
    }
}
```

This is closer to what I need however unless I'm not seeing something it seems that this output could be a mix of dicts and lists which will be more difficult to loop over within a django template?

Comment: It's not clear what your desired outcome it. What format do you want? It doesn't really make sense to say you want the items grouped, but also want it similar to the original list. Also, what is `append_value()`?

Comment: So it would be the date as they key with the items as its values, such as [ { date: {item}, {item} }, { date: {item} } ] and at the same time having the date as a single value, not a tuple containing the month and year separately.

Comment: If the date is to be the key, which date? You are grouping by only month/year which means the items in your groups will not all have the same date.

Comment: I've updated my answer which should explain clearer about the grouping I'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the groupby key the string you want my formatting the date. Then you can just use it in a dict comprehension. It is easier to create the data structure if the values are constantly lists. It will probably also be easier to use it.

```
from itertools import groupby
import datetime

lst = [
    {'title': 'in the past','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 18, 0, 0)},
    {'title': 'Just another event','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 19, 7)},
    {'title': 'earlier today 9am','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 9, 0)},
    {'title': 'greater than .now()','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 23, 0)},
    {'title': 'another one','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 10, 0)},
    {'title': 'Me testing the latest event','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 12, 0)},
    {'title': '18 Nov 20','date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 20, 27)},
    {'title': '18 January 2021','date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 20, 0)},
    {'title': '18 March 21','date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 20, 0)}
]

groups = groupby(lst, key=lambda x: (x['date_time'].strftime("%B %Y")))

{k: list(g) for k, g in groups}
```

Result:

```
{'March 2020': [{'title': 'in the past',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 18, 0, 0)}],
 'October 2020': [{'title': 'Just another event',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 1, 19, 7)},
  {'title': 'earlier today 9am',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 9, 0)},
  {'title': 'greater than .now()',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 23, 0)},
  {'title': 'another one',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 10, 0)},
  {'title': 'Me testing the latest event',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 30, 12, 0)}],
 'November 2020': [{'title': '18 Nov 20',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 18, 20, 27)}],
 'January 2021': [{'title': '18 January 2021',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 18, 20, 0)}],
 'March 2021': [{'title': '18 March 21',
   'date_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 18, 20, 0)}]}
```

Comment: A beautiful and elegant solution! The result is in exactly the format I needed too. I forgot to accept this as the answer before but found myself needing to do another grouping using slightly different data and after searching a while remembered that I had asked about it before, and it has helped me twice now! Thank you again.